# Efficiently checking for a rare occurrence

Tags: perl, if-statement

I have to process many millions of data records. A data record has a record-type string at the beginning of a record. Processing is record-type-dependent but does not require to 'if'/'elsif' the type, just selecting an array-slice mask from a hash.

However, on the order of once-per-million I might encounter a record type that require a totally different kind of processing.

I hate to insert an 'if' testing for this record type that will return 'true' so rarely.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Meir

Comment: Just use an if. Read about branch prediction if you're worried about performance.

Comment: On error, try alternative processing?

Comment: I presume you are reading your data from a disk file? If so, then the time taken to read each record will be much greater than the time to execute an `if` statement.

Comment: @Borodin: Yes, from a disk, but I am sure the OS buffers large chunks of data so it is not individual records.

Comment: @TLP: I don't understand your comment. The Once-in-a-million occurrence is not an error. It requires a re arrangement of array-slice masks.

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked the performance with and without an `if` statement? If not, this sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: @MeirG: Certainly the IO system will buffer the input to speed things up, but that doesn't mean that it takes no time at all to read the data: it simply makes it possible to approach the maximum read speed of the disk. A reasonable average disk read speed is 100MB per second. Say your records are 100 bytes each, that means you can read 1 million records per second, or 1μs per record. A 2011 Intel Core i5 processor runs at 83,000 MIPS, and so can execute 83,000 instructions in the time taken to read one record. It is pointless to avoid a few test and branch instructions amongst all that.

Comment: @MeirG Presumably, the difference in processing requires some difference in the records. Presumably, such a difference will be noticeable by some error in the processing. Or noticeable in some way through the normal processing?

Comment: @Borodin: Hmmm... very convincing! and records are about 130 bytes.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: No, not yet, but I will. And thanks to the kind and responsive people here I'll post the results here.

Comment: But still, what if an almost superfluous 'if' condition indeed have a significant impact? Don't we have in Perl a hardware interrupt like mechanism that trips and jumps to some exception handler? (Sorry, not a very experienced Perl programmer. :(

Comment: @TLP: I see what you mean, but in this case no error checking is done. The source has already been checked, so nothing akin to a hardware interrupt will take place.

Comment: It might help if you gave us some concrete examples of what your data looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: Don't worry about it.

The speed of your CPU is considerably higher than that of your disk IO, so an `if` test is just not going to make a lot of difference - even if you ignored e.g. branch prediction algorithms.

An SSD will do about 1500 IO operations per second, and to quote Borodin from the comments:

> A reasonable average disk read speed is 100MB per second. Say your records are 100 bytes each, that means you can read 1 million records per second, or 1μs per record. A 2011 Intel Core i5 processor runs at 83,000 MIPS, and so can 
>   execute 83,000 instructions in the time taken to read one record. It is pointless to avoid a few test and branch instructions amongst all that.

Basically this is true in any code - your IO to storage is almost always your limiting factor, because CPUs have followed [Moore's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law), but the actual rotational speed of a spinning disk hasn't really changed in 15+ years. SSDs are something of a revolutionary change, but they're still too expensive to use as bulk storage options (and even if that wasn't true, they're *still* going to be the bottleneck on a sustained data transfer/processing operation).

Comment: [A modern, middle of the road SSD will do more like 10,000 to 100,000 IOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS#Solid-state_devices), the IO / CPU gap has closed considerably.  I still think the OP shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: It's true - as a storage engineer I'm eagerly watching the SSD trend. They still suffer from scalability - the device size vs. controllers vs. footprint on the floor mean we're still running 90% spinning rust by capacity. (By iops, it's a fairly even split between SATA/FC/SSD).